# SimCity 2013: is the truck shipping bug fixed?

Tags: simcity-2013

I got into the new SimCity when the cities of tomorrow came out.

I enjoyed the game, but there was a fatal bug in the game that shipping trucks would ultimately get stuck on the map.  Consequently, the economy would crash and you would burn through cash like nobody's business.  Game over.

So I returned the game.  It was literally unplayable.

Has this bug finally been solved?  I'm thinking about getting the game again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific patch note for that defect since CoT launch.

http://help.ea.com/en/article/simcity-updates/

Additionally, there is a similar bug with high school buses where they carry students out of your city and return empty (the students depopulate over time).

Comment: But where do they go? inglip.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it still happens, online at least for me. All my delivery trucks are stuck right past the entry point on the railroad tracks. Stacked up on another you cant even discern how many there are.

My opinion is that it remains a bug, caused by heavy traffic on that intersection. Makes no sense that it would be purposefully done, eventually the trucks would have to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was not a bug, but an effect of traffic. When I rebuilt the city with a different street layout using some tutorial videos people have made the traffic and shipments could actually come into my city.... you have to lay your streets to free up that bottleneck at the 1 entrance to your city

Comment: ...are you BAMF4bacon?

Comment: I am... Batman.

Answer (score 0):

I repurchased the game.  During my break, the game was completely recoded to allow offline play.  Apparently, this bug was fixed in that process, in so far as it doesn't reoccur.

Traffic can dramatically slow down truck trade.  Specifically, this bug is when traffic moves but the trucks stay put everywhere on the map.  No matter how bad traffic is, they should  move slowly.

Comment: EA says "completely recoded", modders say "tweaked a bit"...

Answer (score -1):

You said 'map' so I assume you mean Region deliveries. Your stuck delivery truck is likely stuck behind traffic in the region. This often occurs when delivering resources to the Great Work or a Global Market delivery. Playing on Cheetah speed while watching your truck from your city drive thru the Region then hit traffic definitely looks like it's stuck.

You can switch to Region view, select the Freight icon, and advance the game speed to Cheetah speed. This will highlight the delivery trucks on the region highways, allow you to vaguely see the traffic (especially if you focus on a city near the truck in question), and the speed will allow the traffic to clear faster and your truck will get closer to it's destination, showing that it's not actually stuck.

If the truck is making a neighbor gift delivery to your city, the truck will not even appear on your Region highway if the truck gets "stalled at the border" as reported by the game through a notification at the top of the screen. This will continue until you resolve the cause of the stall in the receiving city.

I've never seen a stuck delivery truck in the city (except what is caused by the Pause game button) especially in version 10.3. City buses will stack up inside each other at popular bus stops and delivery trucks will stack at the Trade Depot or Trade Port pick-up/drop-off point. However, this stacking doesn't hinder the vehicle's ability to depart at the appropriate time.